# Using Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, Getting error "Problem generating manifest....An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: desktop-bridge

I'm working on VSTO (WinForm) application. I want to use `LaunchUriAsync()` to launch a second packaged desktop app. I've been trying to get the right references into the VSTO project to allow for the call to Windows.System.Launcher.LauncherUriAsync().

I've followed various guidance. I tried following the guidance to enable [UWP APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

I also tried the new [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/calling-windows-10-apis-from-a-desktop-application-just-got-easier/#435Se78760Gr65cG.97).

In each case, I can bring in `using Windows.System;` and I can correctly reference `LaunchUriAsync()`.

Now, when I build, I'm getting errors on every `winmd` file in the references.

The error is:
Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly `filename`. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I've tried setting the `local copy` property in each `winmd` file to false, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all UWP APIs are allowed to be called from any desktop app. You need to follow the [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app#the-dualapipartition-attribute) to determine whether an API you want to call from your desktop application is supported.

Then, if you check the [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher) class, the DualApiPartition attribute is not listed, the API does need the calling app to have a package identity. Therefore a WPF, Windows Forms, or Win32 app is not allowed to call the API unless the app has been converted to a UWP app.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. It's incorrect to try and run the Launcher class from a WinForms app, which is what VSTO really is. I ended up using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(), which seems to work for my case.